# How to get a document contents from Firestore by custom object? (Android - Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a document contents from Firestore. The following image link shows the database structure [Firestore database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBoO9.png)

**What I want:** I want to get a document contents by a custom object and add the contents to a list.

**The problem:** I'm getting this error: 
**E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aalmesbah.turoodpilot, PID: 12160
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped**

I tried to get the document content by **get() and getString()** methods and it worked fine the problem is only with the **toObject()**?

I've searched and tried some suggested solutions from other questions here like add default values for the data class, but it didn't work, unfortunately.

**data class code:**

```
data class UserInfo (val name: String? = "",
                 val email: String? = "",
                 val phoneNum: String? = "",
                 val address: String? = "") {
    constructor(): this("","","", "" )
```

}

**Profile Fragment code:** (where the document contents suppose to be shown)

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    return view
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val userID = auth.currentUser?.uid
    val docRef = db.collection("users").document(userID!!)

    docRef.addSnapshotListener(EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> { documentSnapshot, e ->

    if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
            return@EventListener
        }

        if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {

            docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
                val userInfo = documentSnapshot.toObject(UserInfo::class.java)

                emailTV.text = userInfo?.email
            }
        } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null")
            }

        })


}
```

}

**sendUserData() method code at Registration activity**

```
private fun sendUserData() {

    val name = userN.text.toString()
    val email = userEm.text.toString()
    val phone = userPhone.text.toString()
    val addressName = addressName.text.toString()
    val area = area.text.toString()
    val block = block.text.toString()
    val street = strees.text.toString()
    val avenue = avenue.text.toString()
    val house = house.text.toString()
    val floor = floor.text.toString()
    val apartment = apartment.text.toString()
    val additionalInfo = additional.text.toString()

    val address = "Addres Name: $addressName \n Area: $area \n B: $block ST: $street Av: $avenue H: $house\n " +
            "Floor: $floor Apartment: $apartment \n Notes: $additionalInfo"

    val userID = auth.currentUser?.uid

    val userData = UserInfo(name, email, phone, address)

    db.collection("users").document(userID!!).set(userData).addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Upload error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a Kotlin data class with `documentSnapshot.toObject`, you're going to have to make each field a nullable `var` instead of `val`.  The Firestore SDK doesn't know how to map document fields into data class constructor argument.

If you want a proper immutable data class with `val` fields, you're going to have to manually read each field out of the document, and call the data class constructor yourself.